Optimal indexing for a big partitioned table
I used Rick James's partitioning and indexing guide to create this a couple of year ago but now after reading the tutorial again I am not so sure I understood it correct and that the below table is optimal.
(guide reference)
I think one of the normal indexes are redundant and not sure if I should leave out the partitioning key column (datetime) or change one of the indexes to have the partitioning key column (datetime) last.
Will having it as part of the index help for performance when selecting for specific datetime range inside a partition?
Also would it be better to perhaps have the primary key (deviceService, datetime) and have an index on the autoincrement (id)?
Time series based table below has about 80+ million rows per monthly partition.
It is almost always queried for a specific datetime range and for a subset of deviceServiceId's.
Partitioning is purely for archiving and table maintenance and not for performance.
CREATE TABLE `serviceResultLinkState` 
(
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deviceServiceId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `priority` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `stable` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `attempts` int(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `retries` int(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `resultState` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`dateTime`),
  KEY `dt_ds_idx` (`deviceServiceId`),
  KEY `datetime_idx` (`dateTime`,`deviceServiceId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24814201874 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci
 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(`dateTime`)
(PARTITION `p_202405` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-06-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p_202406` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-07-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p_202407` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-08-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p_202408` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-09-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p_202409` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-10-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p_202410` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-11-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p_202411` VALUES LESS THAN ('2024-12-01 00:00:00') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p_max` VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB);



"not sure the table is optimal"  Optimal for what?  Speed?  Space?  Inserts?  Updates?  Selects?  The table look like it will "work".
The table definition hints that it might be purged after about 6 months.  If so, what you have looks fine.
"think one of the normal indexes are redundant" -- The 3 (including the PK) you have are not redundant.  Some may not be used, that is a different question.  WIthout seeing the main queries, I cannot address this question.
"primary key (deviceService, datetime)" -- If this pair is necessarily "unique" then it may be a better PK.
id may not be needed if you have the above PK. (Again, it depends on the queries.)  If id is needed, then INDEX(id) in addition to the above PK is sufficient for AUTO_INCREMENT.
"Will having it as part of the index help for performance when selecting for specific datetime range inside a partition?"  Maybe.  Let me see the query.  The question boils down to "Is this composite index useful for this query?".  I discuss "what is the best composite index for this query" in a companion Index Cookbook
"queried for a specific datetime range and for a subset of deviceServiceId's" -- WHERE x IN (...) AND y BETWEEN... is hard to optimize.  The partitioning will help in some cases, not others.  EXPLAIN SELECT ... will either show which partitions are being used for the query, but do not give much clue of how well the IN or BETWEEN is being handled within each partition that it uses.
"Partitioning is purely for archiving and table maintenance and not for performance." -- This seems to nullify the rest of your questions.
Is this "senior" data?  If so, I have more comments.

More

"So I was wondering if having a PK by deviceServiceId,datetime would improve the select lookup time."  -- Yes.  See my discussion here:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor
(I would have weekly partitions and purge weekly.  But monthly is OK.)
When plotting data,...  If the plot has millions of data points, it is better to have only hundreds or thousands.  Do this via a Summary Table
I would eschew id even for "maintenance" operations. In several situations, id leads to unneeded overhead.
WHERE x IN (...) AND y BETWEEN... might be replaceable by a UNION ALL.  It depends.
"senior data" -- I guess I was having a "senior moment".  I meant "sensor data".

Still more

Rollup (via Summary table(s)) by hour and/or day.  If you need "by hour" for anything, that can probably double for "by day".
Rollups could (in desirable) include max / min.


My answer to these further questions posted.

So yes this is "sensor" data and we expect to have up to 602425000(devices) = 36,000,000 records per day in some of these tables, as the sensor data is measured by minute or if not we create tables that convert state changes to samples by minute.
Graphs will be plotting by minute but only for one specific device at a time and only for a specific period for example 2 days and then longer periods would be rolled up to hourly or daily.
For reporting this is rolled up into daily avg metrics. For example uptime %.

@StephanVos - I added still more.

Thank @RickJames very helpful feedback and suggestions, much appreciated.

"primary key (deviceService, datetime)" -- If this pair is necessarily "unique" then it may be a better PK.
This would mean that I then don't need:
KEY dt_ds_idx (deviceServiceId),
KEY datetime_idx (dateTime,deviceServiceId)?

@StephanVos - True.  Well you might need an index starting with dateTime for some obscure queries, but it is unlikely.


"not sure the table is optimal" Optimal for what? Speed? Space?
Inserts? Updates? Selects? The table look like it will
"work".
(Speed of select are more of an concern as this is mainly used to plot a timeseries graph of metrics for a specific deviceServiceId. So
I was wondering if having a PK by deviceServiceId,datetime would
improve the select lookup time. See main query further down below)

"The table definition hints that it might be purged after about 6
months. If so, what you have looks fine."
(Correct)

"think one of the normal indexes are redundant" -- The 3 (including
the PK) you have are not redundant. Some may not be used, that is a
different question. Without seeing the main queries, I cannot address
this question.
(This is the most common type of query run against this table that has data by interval minute. Might have a datetime variation
depending on the period that the data is queried for:
select sr.dateTime, sr.alias, sr.resultState from serviceResultLinkState sr where sr.deviceServiceId = 567403 and
dateTime >= curdate() - interval 24 hour;)

"primary key (deviceService, datetime)" -- If this pair is
necessarily "unique" then it may be a better PK.
(I think it will be unique as metrics are persisted every minute for a deviceServiceId so the timestamp should be unique)

"id may not be needed if you have the above PK. (Again, it depends on
the queries.) If id is needed, then INDEX(id) in addition to the
above PK is sufficient for AUTO_INCREMENT."
(Index on id has been beneficial in the past as it allows one to address a specific block of data for maintenance type operations
using id range in a quicker fashion but maybe a modified pk will have
the same benefit?)

"Will having it as part of the index help for performance when
selecting for specific datetime range inside a partition?" Maybe. Let
me see the query. The question boils down to "Is this composite index
useful for this query?". I discuss "what is the best composite index
for this query" in a companion Index Cookbook
"queried for a specific datetime range and for a subset of deviceServiceId's" -- WHERE x IN (...) AND y BETWEEN... is hard to
optimize. The partitioning will help in some cases, not others.
EXPLAIN SELECT ... will either show which partitions are being used
for the query, but do not give much clue of how well the IN or
BETWEEN is being handled within each partition that it uses.
(The IN is in actual fact not common for accessing this table - for rollup summary processes I would either address each
devicveServiceId individually or join on another table filtered for
the list of deviceServiceId's we are interested in)

"Partitioning is purely for archiving and table maintenance and not
for performance." -- This seems to nullify the rest of your
questions.
(We would almost always query this table for recent data so the only time it would perhaps span two partitions is for example looking
at data for the last 7 days which could have some days in the earlier
partition)

Is this "senior" data? If so, I have more comments.
(Not sure what you mean by this?)


